# Is it possible to reference the resource name inside the resource itself

Tags: terraform

I'd like to use a resource name inside the resource itself to avoid string duplication and copy/paste errors.

```
resource "aws_instance" "bastion-euw3-infra-01" {
  ami           = "ami-078db6d55a16afc82"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name      = "sylvain"

  user_data = templatefile("./scripts/cloudinit.yaml", {
    hostname          = "bastion-euw3-infra-01"
    tailscale_authkey = var.tailscale_authkey
  })

  network_interface {
    device_index         = 0
    network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.bastion-euw3-infra-01.id
  }

  tags = {
    Name        = "bastion-euw3-infra-01"
    Environment = "infra"
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [user_data]
  }
}
```

Basically I'd like to replace `"bastion-euw3-infra-01"` inside the resource with some kind of var, e.g.:

```
resource "aws_instance" "bastion-euw3-infra-01" {
  ...

  user_data = templatefile("./scripts/cloudinit.yaml", {
    hostname          = ___name___
    tailscale_authkey = var.tailscale_authkey
  })

  ...

  tags = {
    Name        = ___name___
    Environment = "infra"
  }

  ...
}
```

Does terraform provide a way to do this ?

Comment: This is exactly what [input variables](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#using-input-variable-values) are for.

Comment: I want to use the name of the terraform resource inside its own definition.

I don't see how input variables can help me here.

Comment: This isn't currently possible - see https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/925 . If you really need to do something like this, consider creating a local value and using it in your tags and hostname fields.

Answer (score 3):

Like mentioned in the comments already, there is no direct support. But is easy to solve ;-)

I will show an example for [gitlab](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/gitlabhq/gitlab/latest/docs), you can transform it to your aws resources yourself.

**UPDATE**: At the end of the answer I posted the pseudo code for your question!

My example will handle the `avatar` and the `avatar_hash` which both belong to the same value (a filename), here the [documentation to the gitlab group](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/gitlabhq/gitlab/latest/docs/resources/group).

In the following steps I will omit the provider declaration for gitlab

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    gitlab = {
      source  = "gitlabhq/gitlab"
      version = "16.3.0"
    }
  }
  backend "http" {
  }
}
```

### Copy & Paste -> bad, and reason for your question

The copy & paste solution will use twice the path to the image. Bad.

```
resource "gitlab_group" "playground" {
  name        = "Playground"
  path        = "playground"
  description = "Try your ideas! Space for spikes! "
  avatar      = "${path.root}/../img/playground.png"
  avatar_hash = filesha256("${path.root}/../img/playground.png")
}
```

### Solution(s)

#### 1st Solution - local variable

Use a [local variable](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/locals) in your terraform file like `src/main.tf`.

```
locals {
  playground_avatar = "${path.root}/../img/playground.png"
}

resource "gitlab_group" "playground" {
  name        = "Playground"
  path        = "playground"
  description = "Try your ideas! Space for spikes! "
  avatar      = local.playground_avatar
  avatar_hash = filesha256(local.playground_avatar)
}
```

#### 2nd Solution - create a module

Use a [module](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules) and re-use the module variables.

Create a file `modules/group/main.tf`.

```
resource "gitlab_group" "default_group" {
  name        = var.name
  path        = var.path
  description = var.description
  avatar      = var.avatar
  avatar_hash = var.avatar != "" ? filesha256(var.avatar) : ""
}
```

Create a file `modules/group/var.tf`

```
variable "name" {
  type = string
}

variable "path" {
  type    = string
  default = ""
}

variable "description" {
  type    = string
  default = ""
}

variable "avatar" {
  description = "A local path to the avatar image to upload."
  type        = string
  default     = ""
}
```

Use in your terraform file `src/main.tf` the module `source = "../modules/group"`

```
module "gitlab_group_playground" {
  source      = "../modules/group"
  path        = "Playground"
  name        = "playground"
  description = "Try your ideas! Space for spikes! "
  avatar      = "${path.root}/../img/playground.png"
}
```

### Ways which will not work

#### Will not work - Reference to itself

```
resource "gitlab_group" "playground" {
  name        = "Playground"
  path        = "playground"
  description = "Try your ideas! Space for spikes! "
  avatar      = "${path.root}/../img/playground.png"
  avatar_hash = filesha256(resource.gitlab_group.playground.avatar)
}
```

Error ❗❗❗: `Configuration for gitlab_group.playground may not refer to itself.`

#### Will not work - Use `self`

```
resource "gitlab_group" "playground" {
  name        = "Playground"
  path        = "playground"
  description = "Try your ideas! Space for spikes! "
  avatar      = "${path.root}/../img/playground.png"
  avatar_hash =  filesha256(self.avatar)
}
```

Error ❗❗❗: `The "self" object is not available in this context. This object can be used only in resource provisioner, connection, and postcondition blocks.`

### Answer to your pseudo code

```
locals {
  my_aws_hostname = "bastion-euw3-infra-01"
}

resource "aws_instance" "bastion-euw3-infra-01" {
  ...

  user_data = templatefile("./scripts/cloudinit.yaml", {
    hostname          = local.my_aws_hostname
    tailscale_authkey = var.tailscale_authkey
  })

  ...

  tags = {
    Name        = local.my_aws_hostname
    Environment = "infra"
  }

  ...
}
```